# Pivot SQL data without aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

So I need to straight pivot my data with no aggregation.  I have tried PIVOT, UNPIVOT, CROSS APPLY, and CASE statements all driving me crazy.

Here is my current data set

| Header | Contract Value | Total Cost | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Original Budget | 1000 | 900 | 100 |
| Change Orders | 100 | 90 | 90 |

And this is what I would like to do.  I want the values in the rows to be the column names.

| Header | Original Budget | Change Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contract Value | 1000 | 100 |
| Total Cost | 900 | 100 |
| Profit | 100 | 10 |

Can someone please point me in  the right direction.

Comment: Please share your query attempt that is not working.

Comment: `pivot my data with no aggregation` Any particular reason for `no aggregation`?

Comment: The data has already been summarized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking is called `Fully Trasnpose` a table in SQL. it can be done with `Unpivot` and `Pivot` or `Cross apply` and `Pivot`
your data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Header         VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,Contract_Value INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Total_Cost     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Profit         INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(Header,Contract_Value,Total_Cost,Profit) VALUES 
('Original Budget',1000,900,100),
('Change Orders',100,90,90);
```

using `Unpivot` and `Pivot`

```
SELECT 
  name AS Header, 
  [Original Budget], 
  [Change Orders] 
FROM 
  (
    select 
      Header, 
      name, 
      value 
    from 
      mytable unpivot (
        value for name in (
          [Contract_Value], [Profit], [Total_Cost]
        )
      ) unpiv
  ) Src PIVOT (
    MAX(value) FOR Header IN (
      [Original Budget], [Change Orders]
    )
  ) Pvt 
ORDER BY 
  [Original Budget] desc
```

using `Cross apply` and `Pivot`

```
select name as header,
      [Original Budget],
      [Change Orders]
from 
(
select Header,name,value1
 From  mytable
 Cross Apply ( values ('Contract_Value',Contract_Value)
                     ,('Total_Cost',Total_Cost)
                     ,('Profit',Profit)
             ) B (name,value1)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value1)
  for Header in ([Original Budget], [Change Orders])
) piv
order by [Original Budget] desc
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YAhBtS54)